# AFNetworking 2 setImageWithURL custom response type image/jpeg

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

Im using AFNetworking 2. I have a `UITableview` and each row contains an image.

The issue is that the response type is `image/pjpeg` which is not an accepted type by default. To get around this I have modified `AFURLResponseSerialization.m` around line 599. Adding this content type to the end of the `self.acceptableContentTypes` declaration.

I would prefer not to modify the source. Is there a proper way to do this in 2.x?

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@my/images/%@",BaseUrl,[o objectForKey:@"ID"]];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
 ];
```

This no longer seems to work:

```
[AFImageRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"image/jpeg"]]
```

#### Update:

I can see the error using the following code:

```
   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];

__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                        success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                            __strong UITableViewCell *strongCell = weakCell;

                            strongCell.imageView.image = image;

                            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: @[indexPath]
                                             withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                            NSLog(@"Your image request succeeded!");
                        } failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Your image request failed...");

                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                            NSLog(@"Error: %@", response);
                        }

 ];
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: image/pjpeg"
```

Comment: You probably don't need to change the code neither subclass. In fact "acceptableContentTypes" is a property of AFHTTPResponseSerializer which is a super class of AFImageResponseSerializer. So once you have created the AFImageResponseSerializer, didn't you try to simply set the new value for acceptableContentTypes? you can append the new content type to the original using [serializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[serializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/jpeg"]]; I didn't test this, I just guessed looking at the code. Did you try this solution?

Comment: I don't create a `AFImageResponseSerializer`, the code above is all I have. I don't know how to modify the serializer when I'm doing a `setImageWithURL` (I do know how to with a normal request like `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`).

Comment: See the response from David Caunt below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set your own [imageResponseSerializer](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.1.0/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h#L65) on a UIImageView instance:

```
AFImageResponseSerializer *serializer = [[AFImageResponseSerializer alloc] init];
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [serializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/pjpeg"];
cell.imageView.imageResponseSerializer = serializer;

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@my/images/%@",BaseUrl,[o objectForKey:@"ID"]];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
];
```

Comment: I just tried that, did work for me. How does `setImageWithURL` know to use `serializer`?

Comment: You can see it [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m#L106) and [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m#L146) - the serializer is associated with the image view and then used when a response is received from the network.

Comment: Im still getting the error, I updated the question with additional code.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit. You need to set the serializer on the imageView, of course. Does this work for you now?

Comment: Perfect. That works now, was wondering how they were associated.

Comment: Is there a way to do this once for all image requests? I really liked that in a v1 approach.

Comment: There's no way with AFNetworking. One way would be to use your own `UIImageView` subclass which sets the serializer. Alternatively you could add your own category to load which sets the serializer then calls one of the `setImageWithURL` methods.

Comment: @DavidCaunt I found a way, although hacky one. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to set accepted MIME types once for image serialisation, albeit it is a bit hacky. `UIImageView+AFNetworking` provides users with a [default `AFImageResponseSerializer`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.4/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/imageResponseSerializer), and it turns out the default [instance is shared](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/2.2.4/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m#L90) across all `UIImageView` instances, unless a custom serialiser was set.

Executing this code at app launch will modify default behaviour of all image views:

```
AFImageResponseSerializer *serializer =
    [[[UIImageView alloc] init] imageResponseSerializer];
NSSet *mimeTypes = [serializer.acceptableContentTypes 
    setByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[@"image/pjpeg", @"image/x-png"]];
[serializer setAcceptableContentTypes:mimeTypes];
```

This approach works perfectly for me, but beware that this doesn't rely on any public contract and may change in future versions. If you choose to use this, **cover this with unit tests** which ensure that instance is indeed shared.

The approach will also break if you execute something like

```
imageView.imageResponseSerializer = [[AFImageResponseSerializer alloc] init];
```

as it will replace the shared instance with the unmodified default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

For those using AFNetworking 3.0, you can simply update responseSerializer on the shared sessionManager.

```
AFImageResponseSerializer* serializer = (AFImageResponseSerializer*)      [UIImageView sharedImageDownloader].sessionManager.responseSerializer;
serializer.acceptableContentTypes = [serializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/jpg"];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using RestKit or AFNetworking 1.3 use

```
[AFImageRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"image/pjpeg"]];
```